# GWT Updating Main Content using EventBus and ActivityMapper - Can GWT help me to do this cleaner?

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to know

1. Am I doing things (the following) too complicated?
2. Is there a better way to update the main content of an activity that allows me to bookmark the event calendar of a store via URL like `#MainPlace:eventCalendar?storeId=<id>`?

I'm having this `ActivityMapper` here

```
public class AppActivityMapper implements ActivityMapper {

    private ClientFactory clientFactory;    
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    // ..

    @Override
    public Activity getActivity(Place place) {

        if (place instanceof LoginPlace) {
            return new LoginActivity((LoginPlace) place, clientFactory);
        } else if (place instanceof MainPlace) {
            if(this.mainActivity == null) {
                this.mainActivity = new MainActivity((MainPlace) place, clientFactory);
            } else {
                this.mainActivity.updateMainContent(((MainPlace) place).getMainContentToken());
            }
            return this.mainActivity;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and a `MainActivity` that controls my `MainView` that is just a menu ond the left side and the main content on the right side.

I want to decouple my views like in [Best Practices for Architecting GWT App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM) which is why I'm trying to control the main content by using events that get fired as something gets clicked in my `MenuView`.

Therefore I am initializing some event handlers in my `MainActivity` that react to clicks on the buttons in my menu to delegate the update to the `MainView`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AbstractActivity implements MainView.MainPresenter {

    @Override
    public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {

        this.mainView = this.clientFactory.getMainView();
        this.mainView.setPresenter(this);
        this.mainView.initialize();

        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        this.eventBus.addHandler(HomeClickedEvent.TYPE, new HomeClickedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onHomeClicked(HomeClickedEvent event) {
                goTo(new MainPlace("home"));
            }
        });

        this.eventBus.addHandler(EventCalendarClickedEvent.TYPE, new EventCalendarClickedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onEventCalendarClicked(EventCalendarClickedEvent eventCalendarClickedEvent) {
                goTo(new MainPlace("eventCalendar?storeId=" + eventCalendarClickedEvent.getStoreId()));
            }
        });

        panel.setWidget(this.mainView.asWidget());
    }

    @Override
    public void goTo(Place place) {
        this.clientFactory.getPlaceController().goTo(place);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMainContent(String currentMainContentToken) {
        this.mainView.updateMainContent(currentMainContentToken);
    }

}
```

this event gets fired by `MenuPresenter.clickedEventCalendar()` that reacts to a click on the corresponding menu entry of the `MenuView`:

```
public class MenuPresenter implements MenuView.MenuPresenter {

    // ..

    @Override
    public void clickedEventCalendar(Long storeId) {
        this.eventBus.fireEvent(new EventCalendarClickedEvent(storeId));
    }
}
```

One of the things I really don't like is this where I append parameters to the token e.g. to display the event calendar of a store given by `storeId`:

```
@Override
public void onEventCalendarClicked(EventCalendarClickedEvent eventCalendarClickedEvent) {
    goTo(new MainPlace("eventCalendar?storeId=" + eventCalendarClickedEvent.getStoreId()));
}
```

is there a cleaner solution for a problem like this in GWT? I don't like the fact that I'd have to parse that string in my actual event calendar. Am I using the `ActivityMapper` wrong or is there simply no other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This question should really be split into several separate ones, but that's maybe something to keep in mind for the future. If you're asking one thing then it's easier to answer thoroughly and others can find the answer easier too.

Anyway, I can see a few improvements:

- use [EventBinder](https://github.com/google/gwteventbinder) to get rid a bit of the cruft when handling and creating new events.
- if you just want to let the presenter know that a button was pressed on in the view (associated with that presenter) sending a custom event over the event bus is a bit of an overkill. Depending on your needs you can expose the button in your view's interface:

  ```
  public interface Display {
      HasClickHandlers getButton();
  }
  ```

  And then just register the `ClickHandler` in your presenter.
  Or, if you need to do something view- *and* presenter- related on the click, register the `ClickHandler` in your view and call the presenter:

  ```
  // In MainView:
  @UiHandler("button")
  void handleClick(ClickEvent event) {
      // Do some stuff with view,
      // like hide a panel or change colour
      panel.setVisible(false);

      // Let the presenter know that a click event has been fired
      presenter.onEventCalendarClicked();
  }
  ```
- you're right - creating `MainPlace` like you are proposing is wrong. You are creating the token too soon - that's what the tokenizer associated with the place is for. You should create `MainPlace` by passing just the `storeId` to the constructor - why should `MainPresenter` (or any other class using this place) should know how to create the token? `MainPlace` should look more like this:

  ```
  public class MainPlace extends Place {
      private final Long storeId;

      public MainPlace(Long storeId) {
          this.storeId = storeId;
      }

      public Long getStoreId() {
          return storeId;
      }

      public static class Tokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<MainPlace> {
          @Override
          public MainPlace getPlace(String token) {
              return new MainPlace(Long.valueOf(token));
          }

          @Override
          public String getToken(MainPlace place) {
              return "eventCalendar?storeId=" + place.getStoreId();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Now, it's the `Tokenizer`'s responisibily to create and parse the token. Just remember to [register it on your PlaceHistoryMapper](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#PlaceHistoryMapper).

Comment: Thanks for the link to EventBinder! Looks very helpful! Regarding the exposure of the buttons: this wouldn't be possible at the moment since I am creating the menu programmatically according to data sent by the server but I see that I might could simplify this part. The problem regarding the token generation here is that `MainPlace` can look like this `MainPlace:home` but as well look like this `MainPlace:storeId=<id>` for example. What I'm trying to accomplish is the possibility for the user to bookmark the page he is viewing.

Comment: For the history I am now using `History.addItem(..)` but it seems like I'm doing it wrong because I can't get rid of an exception that tells me that `SimplePanel` can only hold one element and I have no idea where this update happens ^^

Comment: If you're using Activities, you shouldn't be using the History API directly (that's what Activities do for you). As for `MainPlace` - it's hard for me to tell, but either split these into separate places (they can both trigger the same activity) or handle it inside the `MainPlace` class (like allow `storeId` to be `null` and then add "home" instead of "storeId" to the token).